# "Some" with singular or plural in the mentioned context?

Tags: some-any

One of the meanings of "some" is:

> an unspecified amount or number of.

Example: "I made some money running errands" ([Source](https://www.google.de/search?q=some&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIR733IR733&oq=some&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i61j0.1887j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

So, can I use "some" with a noun that might be singular or plural? For example:

> X should satisfy some physiological condition.

In the above sentence, it might be just one condition or more than one. Is that a right way to say that having in mind that "some" is used for unspecified number? Or do I have to use a plural s with parentheses:

> X should satisfy some physiological condition(s).

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/some_1) has what is probably a better treatment (though your link is unhelpful). /  'A should satisfy some physiological condition' could be a generalised statement awaiting the spelling out of one or more such physiological condition/s, or without context, default to 'There must be _some_ physiological condition that A happens to satisfy.'

Comment: Sure.  "I ate some sheep just now."

Answer (score 2):

The use of "some" as "an unspecified number of" is typically only used with either plural nouns or uncountables (words that do not distinguish between singular and plural).

Uncountables appear as singular nouns, but have no plural equivalent. "Money", as you used as an example, is an uncountable noun, as is "water", "air", "space", etc.

Comment: So, "some condition" does not mean "some condition(s)"? Do I have to add (s) to show that it might or might not be plural?

Comment: In this case, "some condition" is interpreted as "an undefined condition", while "some conditions" is interpreted as "an undefined _number_ of conditions"

Answer (score 2):

*Some* in "some physiological condition" is grammatical, but it matches this definition, not the one you were going for:

> - used to refer to someone or something that is unknown or unspecified
>     <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/some)</sub>

(Note that Oxford Dictionaries is the source for your definition and example sentence too.)

---

There are several different ways you could word it. What you wrote will work (here's a [similar example](https://books.google.com/books?id=t5WFOzkk5nYC&pg=PA63&dq="some+condition(s)")). And here's another way that works:

> A should satisfy at least one physiological condition.